# beautiful soup find all <url> tag in xml

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
xml = BeautifulSoup('xml.xml' "html5lib")
        print(xml.find_all('url'))
```

But I got en empty array as a returned result
What do I do?

This is my xml file just in case 
[image: an example of my xml file]

Comment: Did you try "html.parser" or "xml" as second argument? html5lib and xml requires external dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

`BeautifulSoup(open('xml.xml') "xml")`

Opens your XML file and parses it using the XML parser.